# Fix background image in gap - skrollr

Tags: skrollr

I'm creating a parallax similar to this example:

http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/classic.html

I would like the third image that appears on scroll to be a fixed background image and not move at all, like on this page with the girl with the sunglasses about halfway down:

http://pollenlondon.com/prism/

I tried removing the transform styles and adding `background-attachment:fixed` but doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply referencing the exact code shown in the classic example html page, there are several values you need to change as reflected below:

```
<div
    class="parallax-image-wrapper parallax-image-wrapper-100"
    data-anchor-target="#kittens + .gap"
    data-bottom-top="transform:translate3d(0px, 200%, 0px)"
    data-top-bottom="transform:translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px)">

    <div
        class="parallax-image parallax-image-100"
        style="background-image:url(images/kitteh3.jpg)"
        data-anchor-target="#kittens + .gap"
        data-bottom-top="transform: translate3d(0px, -100%, 0px);"
        data-top-bottom="transform: translate3d(0px, 100%, 0px);"
    ></div>
</div>
```

You'll be changing both the `parallax-image-wrapper` and `parallax-image` height values to 100 instead of 50. Honestly, I don't see any benefit to having a 50% height for the wrapper or bg image itself. Maybe there's a reason I'm missing, but I would expect anyone to want the bg image to span the entire height of the viewport as the exposed gap moves over it.

Because of this, I just set these two classes as having `height:100%` in my styles, and then drop the extra height classes applied in the html code for each image group above & outside the `#skrollr-body`. Not critical to do this, but it'll clean up your code a bit.

Then, change the `data-bottom-top` attribute for the `parallax-image-wrapper` to 200% y-axis value for translate3d to mirror what you see in the first two image groups.

Lastly, change the y-axis transform3d values for `parallax-image` from -60%/60% to -100%/100%. This will cause the bg image to remain static as the exposed gap scrolls over top of it and will make it appear to be fixed.